# Filling gaps in multipart polygons without creating overlapping polygons

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, r-sf

I would like to fill in the gaps of multipart polygons to create a single extent polygon for each feature.

I have tried to do a 250m buffer on a multipart feature and then do a 250m negative buffer. This almost works, but creates polygons that overlap with adjacent features.

Is there a method that does something similar to my code below but ensures polygons don't overlap?

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Iyk7XhPHY5rs4OLI56b3GHibZIPdDnpo" , destfile="Areas.zip")
unzip("Areas.zip")
Areas <- st_read("Areas.gpkg") 

Area_1 <- Areas %>%
    filter(name == "Area 1") %>% 
    st_buffer(., 250) %>% 
    st_buffer(., -250) 
    
New_Areas <- bind_rows(Area_1, Areas %>% filter(name != "Area 1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited: `concaveman` approach

You can create a hull around your object, and create a polygon using that coordinates, as an alternative approach. The package `concaveman` is very useful for this task, see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354276/using-r-and-sf-create-an-concave-envelope-polygon-around-multilinestring :

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Iyk7XhPHY5rs4OLI56b3GHibZIPdDnpo",
  destfile = "Areas.zip",
  mode = "wb"
)
unzip("Areas.zip", exdir = ".")

Areas <- st_read("Areas.gpkg")
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 272036.8 ymin: 432143.8 xmax: 288261.8 ymax: 446143.8
#> Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid

Area_1 <- Areas %>%
  filter(name == "Area 1")

# Use concaveman
library(concaveman)
geom_convex <- concaveman(st_coordinates(Area_1)[, 1:2]) %>%
  list() %>%
  st_polygon() %>%
  st_sfc()

Area_convex <- st_sf(st_drop_geometry(Area_1),
  geom = geom_convex,
  crs = st_crs(Areas)
)

plot(st_geometry(Area_convex), col = "red")
plot(st_geometry(Area_1), add = TRUE, border = "blue")
```

[image]

```r
New_Areas <- bind_rows(Area_convex, Areas %>% filter(name != "Area 1"))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = New_Areas, fill = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Old answer: stick to buffer approach

You can remove the overlapping parts with `st_difference()` before re-merging:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Iyk7XhPHY5rs4OLI56b3GHibZIPdDnpo",
  destfile = "Areas.zip",
  mode = "wb"
)
unzip("Areas.zip", exdir = ".")

Areas <- st_read("Areas.gpkg")
#> Reading layer `Areas' from data source 
#>   `/tmp/Rtmpw1wNtg/reprex-2125ac8065c-loyal-rat/Areas.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 272036.8 ymin: 432143.8 xmax: 288261.8 ymax: 446143.8
#> Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid

ggplot(Areas) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
Area_1 <- Areas %>%
  filter(name == "Area 1") %>%
  st_buffer(250) %>%
  st_buffer(-250)

NoArea_1 <- Areas %>% filter(name != "Area 1")

Area_1_end <- st_difference(Area_1, st_union(st_geometry(NoArea_1)))
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

st_overlaps(Area_1, NoArea_1, sparse = FALSE)
#>      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

st_overlaps(Area_1_end, NoArea_1, sparse = FALSE)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

ggplot(Area_1) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = Area_1_end, fill = NA, color = "red")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(Area_1_end) +
  geom_sf(fill = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = NoArea_1, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

```r
New_Areas <- bind_rows(Area_1_end, Areas %>% filter(name != "Area 1"))

New_Areas
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 272036.8 ymin: 432143.8 xmax: 288261.8 ymax: 446143.8
#> Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
#>     name                           geom
#> 1 Area 1 POLYGON ((272911.8 441747.1...
#> 2 Area 2 MULTIPOLYGON (((280486.8 43...
#> 3 Area 3 MULTIPOLYGON (((272061.8 44...
#> 4 Area 4 MULTIPOLYGON (((286586.8 43...
#> 5 Area 5 MULTIPOLYGON (((282261.8 44...
#> 6 Area 6 MULTIPOLYGON (((285261.8 43...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `concaveman` approach does **not** generate non-overlaping polygons.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Iyk7XhPHY5rs4OLI56b3GHibZIPdDnpo",
  destfile = "Areas.zip",
  mode = "wb"
)
unzip("Areas.zip", exdir = ".")

Areas <- st_read("Areas.gpkg")
#> Reading layer `Areas' from data source 
#>   `\Temp\RtmpoRVQgr\reprex-1a645c5d56e-goofy-coney\Areas.gpkg' 
#>   using driver `GPKG'
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 272036.8 ymin: 432143.8 xmax: 288261.8 ymax: 446143.8
#> Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
Area_1 <- Areas %>%
  filter(name == "Area 1")

NoArea_1 <- filter(Areas, name != "Area 1")

# Original areas don´t overlap
st_overlaps(Area_1, NoArea_1, sparse = FALSE)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Use concaveman
library(concaveman)
geom_convex <- concaveman(st_coordinates(Area_1)[, 1:2]) %>%
  list() %>%
  st_polygon() %>%
  st_sfc()

Area_convex <- st_sf(st_drop_geometry(Area_1),
  geom = geom_convex,
  crs = st_crs(Areas)
)

# New areas do overlap
st_overlaps(Area_convex, NoArea_1, sparse = FALSE)
#>      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So if you want to use the `concaveman` solution you need to use `st_difference`, like in the buffer aproach.

```r
# Need to use st_difference
Area_convex_end <- st_difference(Area_convex, st_union(st_geometry(NoArea_1)))
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

st_overlaps(Area_convex_end, NoArea_1, sparse = FALSE)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The reason to prefer one solution or the other should be based on the shape of the extruded polygon.